# Python: how to compute a fast measure of robustness on a network?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, networkx, computation

I am working with a regular `NxN` network, and I need to determine a measure of its robustness (namely, the ability to withstand failures). To do this, I am using the [average node connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)), which is described by [this function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.connectivity.average_node_connectivity.html#networkx.algorithms.connectivity.connectivity.average_node_connectivity).

However, this calculation is proving extremely slow and computationally demanding, as you can see below. I am supposed to run the script below `60,000` times, so time is a very crucial factor. For this reason I am willing to reduce the size of the network, but I want to find the best compromise between network size and computational demand.

**My question:**

**Is there a faster way to come up with the same result? Or is there another measure you suggest in order to avoid long computations?**

The script and the timings:

```
'''
Timing the average node connectivity function
'''

from __future__ import division
import networkx as nx
import time

#Lattice network
N=10 #This can be 10, 20, 30, ...
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))

start_time = time.clock()
conn=nx.average_node_connectivity(G)
print('N: '+str(N))
print('Avg node conn: '+str(round(conn, 3)))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.clock() - start_time))
```

The first two timings:

```
N: 10
Avg node conn: 3.328
--- 6.80954619325 seconds --- #This must be multiplied by 60,000

N: 20
Avg node conn: 3.636
--- 531.969059161 seconds --- #This must be multiplied by 60,000
```

Comment: what does "robustness" mean to you in this context?

Comment: The ability to withstand failures.

Comment: So I'm going to assume that what David provided is what you're after - but you should be aware, there are lots of different "failures" that could happen.  Depending on what that means to you this may or may not be the right quantity to calculate.  We could be talking about nodes failing.  We could be talking about edges failing.  Withstanding failures could mean the entire network remains connected, or it could mean just that a large fraction of the network remains connected, or it could mean that the path lengths do not be come long...  etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That NetworkX function has to work with a digraph, so it's using the brute force algorithm of computing V*(V-1) flows. Since you have an undirected graph, you can instead compute the [Gomory--Hu tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomory%E2%80%93Hu_tree) in V-1 flows and then use the tree structure to determine min cuts quickly (actually, you can compute the average node connectivity from the G--H tree in linear or maybe linearithmic time, but I expect that quadratic will probably be fine).

(Shameless plug: since you're working with planar graphs with unit capacities, if you're desperate for speed, you could implement my and Philip Klein's linear-time max flow algorithm, but I expect that the usual algorithms will be roughly linear-time in practice.)

Comment: And here is someone who's actually familiar with the problem. Great answer! I'm not going to remove mine, but this is much more informative.

Answer (score 3):

The average node connectivity calculated here is the average of local node connectivity over all **pairs** of nodes of G. So this function will go over all possible pairs which makes it so slow. One suggestion would be to leave the size of your network as you want it but then randomly sample from all possible pairs of nodes and compute a connectivity estimate based on that sample.